# How to convert a month number into a month name in python

Tags: list, numbers, python-3.2

How do you get a list to correspond with a user input. If I had a list like:

```
month_lst = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
              'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

How do I get an input of 1 to return 'January' as the answer?

```
input('Enter the number to be converted: ')
```

Also the input needs to check with the list to make sure it is within 1-12, so inputing 15 would read an error message.

Answer (score 15):

The calendar library can provide what you want, see the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html

```
calendar.month_name[month_number] #for the full name
```

or

```
calendar.month_abbr[month_number] #for the short name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
month_lst = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
              'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
try:
    month = int(input('Enter the number to be converted: '))
    if month < 1 or month > 12:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        print(month_lst[month - 1])
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid number")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very old question. But have I found a very simple solution.

```
import calendar

def get_month_name(month_number):
    try:
        return calendar.month_name[month_number]
    except IndexError:
        print("'{}' is not a valid month number".format(month_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get input from the user with `input()` or `raw_input()`, depending on your python version (the latter for Python 2.x).

You can turn the string that gives you into an integer with `int()`.

Finally, you can look up the strings in your list with `month_lst[some_integer]` where `some_integer` is one less than the integer you got from the user.